# Operator In/Contains for a Rules Engine

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement the IN operator for a rules engine
LeftResult IN RightResult

```
object leftResult = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, leftParams.ToArray());
object rightResult = methodInfo.Invoke(classInstance, rightParams.ToArray());
```

leftResult is a list of values  and RightResult is a comma seperated string.

```
 case Enumerations.ComparisonType.In:

                    if (leftResult != null && rightResult != null)
                    {
                        List<object> leftList;
                        List<object> rightList;
                        if (leftResult.ToString().Contains(","))
                        {
                            rightList = rightResult as List<object>;
                            if ((leftResult.ToString().Split(',')).Contains(rightList[0].ToString())) result = true;
                            else result = false;
                        }
                        else if (rightResult.ToString().Contains(","))
                        {
                            leftList = leftResult as List<object>;
                            if ((rightResult.ToString().Split(',')).Contains(leftList[0].ToString())) result = true;
                            else result = false;
                        }
                        else if (rightResult.GetType() == typeof(List<object>))
                        {

                            if ((rightResult as List<object>).Contains(leftResult)) result = true;
                            else result = false;
                        }
                        else if (leftResult.GetType() == typeof(List<object>))
                        {

                            if ((leftResult as List<object>).Contains(rightResult)) result = true;
                            else result = false;
                        }
                    }
```

This is the code I have done to handle cases where the left or the right could be a list or  comma separated string. But it is not working correctly. Can anyone suggest a better way of implementing In/Contains operator for a rules engine

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My favorite way of doing these sort of tests is to use a `HashSet<T>`

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383091(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383091%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

First convert your tow arrays/strings into a HashSet and then use one of the builtin methods like `IntersectWith` or `Overlaps` depending on the logic you need.

Comment: Thanks. Ok so first convert both the left and right to a hashset and use the builtin methods.Ok thank you very much